# OnClick: Passing String as Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to pass a string as a parameter of the following:

`<div id="menubutton1" class="menubutton lightbox" onclick="lightbox(1000, 410, hello)">`

How would I make "hello" become a parameter. The integers pass without problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Try using 'hello'

Comment: "hello" should be a string. So `'hello'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add quotes to the string parameter:

```
<div id="menubutton1" class="menubutton lightbox" onclick="lightbox(1000, 410, 'hello')">
```

will work.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes around your string like so:

```
<div id="menubutton1" class="menubutton lightbox" onclick="lightbox(1000, 410, 'hello')">
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `'` before hello and a `'` after hello:
`onclick="lightbox(1000, 410, 'hello')"`

Answer (score 0):

The content of the onclick property is handled as Javascript

```
<div onclick="HERE IS JAVASCRIPT"></div>
```

So you should use `'hello'` while you are using double quote for onclick property,

or `"hello"` else using single quote.

Should either use one of it to represent that `hello` is a string, not a variable name.